# refer an enumerator value with specified index

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Assume I have an enumerable object `enum` and now I want to get the third item.

I know one of a general approach is convert into an array and then access with index like:

```
enum.to_a[2]
```

But this way will create a temporary array and it might be inefficient.

Now I use:

```
enum.each_with_index {|v, i| break v if i == 2}
```

But this is quite ugly and redundant.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`take`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) to peel off the first three elements and then [`last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-last) to grab the third element from the array that `take` gives you:

```
third = enum.take(3).last
```

If you don't want to generate any arrays at all then perhaps:

```
# If enum isn't an Enumerator then 'enum = enum.to_enum' or 'enum = enum.each'
# to make it one.
(3 - 1).times { enum.next }
third = enum.next
```

Comment: This looks better but, if I want a very large number as index, it will still generate a very big temporary array for it.

Comment: @ShouYa: I added another array-less option while you were commenting. You still have to tick through `enum` one-by-one but there's nothing you can do about that (in general).

Comment: Using next is a smart suggestion. I would be curious to see what the performances implications are compared to converting a collection to an array.

Comment: @OscarDelBen: That depends greatly on the enumerator. If you start with an enumerator that is backed by a 2G file then converting to an array will be horrendous but calling `next` a couple times will be almost free. Technically, an Enumerator doesn't even have to be finite so there's no guarantee that `to_a` will even work.

Comment: @muistooshort Well, but isn't values in ruby implemented as references? Passing references as argument won't consume too much, right? I like you manner too but I feel that is still lack of readability.

Comment: @ShouYa: But if your Enumerator is reading a 2G file line by line, you still have to read the entire thing into memory and wrap the strings with all the usual per-reference baggage from Ruby; there goes well over 2G of RAM. And if you have an Enumerator that simply returns `11` every time you call `next` then `to_a` cannot even work. You can monkey patch that code into Enumerator if you find it too difficult to read.

Comment: @muistooshort Um, it's reasonable. That is another advantage to use `next` indeed. Actually I don't actually have so high requirement for that. I was just feel strange how to implement this simple function efficiently. Thank you.

Comment: a more declarative way to convert something to enumerator: `xs.to_enum`

Answer (score 5):

Alternative to mu's answer using [enumerable-lazy](https://github.com/yhara/enumerable-lazy) or Ruby 2.1. As lazy as using `next` but much more declarative:

```
enum.lazy.drop(2).first
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, to access a member by index it has to be converted to an array (otherwise you wouldn't have an index in the first place), so your code looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Um, no. If `e` is an `Enumerator` then `2.times { e.next }` will tick off and throw away the first two values and a third `e.next` will give you the third one without generating any arrays.

Comment: @muistooshort yep, I replied to your thread. And you're right in that respect.